# 503 error, the service is unavailable after server restore

Tags: restore, internal-server-error

I have restored the sharepoint WFE server to roll back some changes, and now I get Service Unavailable

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

My farm consists of 1 WFE and 1 SQL server.

What could the reason for the error be?

Comment: can you check IIS pools and sites if are Started?

Comment: The server says "the specified network password is not correct" when I try to log on so I c an't check IIS either...

Comment: probably problem with the time on servers, try to update it  (try to log as local computer admin) or try to update time with an PS with remote control

Comment: after you log to your server, probably IIS pools will be stopped, cause there were maybe problems with identities, so refresh paswords and start pools and sites.

Comment: if it will be done, i will create answer and you can mark it :) hope it helps

Comment: I am pretty sure the passwords did not  change or expire... Nor should have the time on server have changed... I just reverted to a server backup of 1 day ago and this happened...

Comment: yes the time probably has changed if you cannot log in, you must set correct time on server, this is not about the passwords but about the verification and some kind of cache...

Answer (score 2):

**This issue usually occurs in case of**

> The App pool of your web application is stopped.

**If you got this issue after the restart that means**

> You have recently changed the password of your **APP pool Identity** from Active Directory that not reflected directly to the IIS and needs to be reflected manually.

---

**In your case,** you can't connect to the IIS and you got

> The specified network password is not correct.

That means there is an issue in your network occurred after the restart, and you should check it with

- your System Admin & network admin.
- or ask for it at https://serverfault.com/
- Also, check [The specified network password is not correct.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42614/getting-specified-network-password-is-not-correct-when-trying-to-change-passwo/80715)

**Once this issue solved, try to**

- Open ISS.
- Go to Application Pools.
- Check the App Pool of your web application.
- Make sure it's started properly, and try to restart it again.
- If it's stopped, try to update the App Pool Identity as the following:

  - Right Click > Advanced Settings.
  - Check Identity, and provide it again in a correct manner.

  [image]

  - Restart The App Pool.
  - Browse your web app that should be browsed properly.

Answer (score 1):

It was actually just a trust relationship issue with AD. Once that was solved server and SharePoint were up.

Comment: Please mark as answer.